The protagonist wins a school contest by answering a question about Shakespeare and "the little death"
I'm trying to identify a movie that I watched in TV between 1998 and 2006. It was a teenage movie, most probably American.
The protagonist was an average teenager that I remember as looking similar to Vinnie from Doogie Howser. He somehow (I think accidentally) became a part of a team that represented his school in some kind of a knowledge contest.
The contest was basically two or more teams, each consisting of about 4 students, answering questions and getting points for correct answers.
There were multiple stages of the contest (county level, state level, etc.), each time there was a host and an audience.
The protagonist's team made it to the finale, which I think was even shown in TV.
Obviously each team consisted of the best students from a given school, so the protagonist, being just an average guy, wasn't a great help for his team. In fact I think that he didn't answer any question until the great finale, it was always one of his team members.
There was also a girl that I think was a part of his team and towards the end of the movie they became attractive to each other.
They spent the evening before the finale together. I think they were only talking. During that evening the protagonist complained that he doesn't understand why the girl likes to study, that he finds it boring, etc. She told him that there are some interesting things even in the English literature and she gave an example of la petite mort, i.e. that when old English poets mentioned dying they often meant having an orgasm.
If the girl was part of the protagonist's team then she wasn't taking part in the finale next day for some reason. It's also possible that she wasn't in his team after all.
During the finale a decisive question is being asked by the host. To everyone's surprise the protagonist signalises that he knows the answer.
Below the dialogue as I remember it:

Host: In one of his sonnets William Shakespeare uses an expression of
  'dying in woman's arms'. In what meaning did Shakespeare use the word
   'die'?
Protagonist: To have a sexual orgasm.
Host: To have a sexual
  orgasm!

Then the protagonist's team wins, everyone's cheering, he gets the girl, etc.
Since the  described plot is rather short it's also possible that it was an episode of a TV series.

It's the 1992 Kid 'n Play movie Class Act.
Your description misses most of the plot, but you describe near the ending, the Knowledge Bowl. Described as "An urban retelling of Mark Twain's The Prince and the Pauper":

After the mix-up is corrected, Blade, Duncan and company are all set free. In an anti-climax, Duncan and Blade both enter a Knowledge bowl in an effort to get Blade back with Ellen. They succeed when Blade answers a tiebreaker question to win the competition, recalling a choice tidbit Ellen once told him. 


Duncan on the left is very Doogie Howser like (preppy, awkward). Michael known as Blade, is not (thuggish, suave). **But they switch places, and pretend to be the opposite, so Blade is very preppy at that scene. 
From the subtitles:

Host: The question is: In William Shakespeare's play "Much Ado About Nothing" Benedict said, "Living in your heart, die in your lap, and be buried in your eyes."  What is the meaning of the word "die" the way he has used?
  Host: Tell your response, please.
[Blade hears/sees a Flashback]
  [Ellen]: ... "Die", as he was on
  used, was meant ...
  ... "Die" meant
  "To experience sexual orgasm."  
Host: That means the ISPRS ... [Interrupted by Buzzer] Sorry.
  Blade: It means to experience sexual orgasm.
  Host: This is the correct answer.

The flashback being towards earlier in the film, when Ellen still didn't know that Blade was only pretending to be the one with a 4.0 GPA.


Turns out I got almost everything wrong, but that's definitely the movie. Thanks!

@ChanandlerBong your mostly right. Your only mixup was that you describe one protagonist as the other. The other one, Duncan, hooks up with a very hood rat type girl too.
